How to use Dapper with derived types
I have about 20 classes that are derived from ModelBase (which contains common things like CreationDate, Id etc).
Using Dapper, it is easy to save and delete these derived classes (all the work is done by the second-last line)
public static bool ModelDelete(ModelBase model, SqlConnection? conn = null, SqlTransaction? trans = null)
{
    bool connectionIsNew = (conn is null);
    bool transactionIsNew = (trans is null);

    try
    {
        if (connectionIsNew) 
            conn = new SqlConnection(Globals.connString);

        if (conn is null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Unable to establish a database connection in Data.ModelDelete");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
             if (conn.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) 
                 conn.Open();
        }

       if (transactionIsNew) 
           trans = conn.BeginTransaction();

        DynamicParameters p = new DynamicParameters();
        p.Add("Id", model.Id, DbType.Int32);
        p.Add("Error", null, DbType.String, ParameterDirection.Output, 8000);
        string spName = $"sp{model.GetType().Name}_Delete";
        int recordsAffected = conn.Execute(spName, p, trans);
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    { }
}

But I don't seem to be able to do the same thing with a Get/Fetch command and end up with
public static ModelBase ModelGet(Type t, int id, SqlConnection? conn = null, SqlTransaction? trans = null, bool withDependents = false)
{
    bool connectionIsNew = (conn is null);
    bool transactionIsNew = (trans is null);
    ModelBase model = default!;

    try
    {
        if (connectionIsNew) 
           conn = new SqlConnection(Globals.connString);

        if (conn is null)
        {
             throw new Exception("Unable to establish a database connection in Data.ModelGet");
        }
        else
        {
            if (conn.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) 
                conn.Open();

            if (transactionIsNew) 
                trans = conn.BeginTransaction();

            var p = new { Id = id };

            string spName = $"sp{t.Name}_Get";

            switch (t.Name)
            {
                case nameof(Account):
                    model = conn.QuerySingle<Account>(spName, p, trans);
                    break;

                case nameof(AccountGroup):
                    model = conn.QuerySingle<AccountGroup>(spName, p, trans);
                    break;

                case nameof(Address):
                    model = conn.QuerySingle<Address>(spName, p, trans);
                    break;

                case nameof(Agency):
                    model = conn.QuerySingle<Agency>(spName, p, trans);
                    break;

and so on with all the different derived model classes. This works but is inelegant. Is there a better way than having a separate conn.QuerySingle<> for each of my derived classes?

As a first step, take a look at pattern matching with switch statements, and maybe even using switch expressions. Not a whole lot less code, but more elegant

public static ModelBase ModelGet<T>(int id, SqlConnection? conn = null, SqlTransaction? trans = null, bool withDependents = false) where T: ModelBase

Out of curiosity, why are you using inheritance (ModelBase) and what does it do, exactly? Modern database application development today tends to prefer simple POCO classes (whereas having to use some kind of common "EntityBase" supertype is something we all stopped doing around 2005 when Hibernate/NHibernate stopped being cool.

Because I'm an enthusiastic amateur that doesn't know what is cool or uncool! ModelBase keeps track of whether the data is new or changed and spits out the necessary parameters for the DB calls. It also lets me have one function each for 'ModelGet', 'ModelDelete' and 'ModelSave' (I don't have separate Insert and Update functions) rather than having to have 38 Gets, 38 Deletes and 38 Save functions. I think thats at least a little bit cool??

since you're depending on Type, you could just convert it into a generic method something like this :
public static T ModelGet<T>(int id, SqlConnection? conn = null, SqlTransaction? trans = null, bool withDependents = false)
where T : ModelBase, class
{
    try
    {
        if (conn is null) 
           conn = new SqlConnection(Globals.connString);

        if (conn.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) 
            conn.Open();
        
        if (trans is null) 
            trans = conn.BeginTransaction();

        return conn.QuerySingle<T>($"sp{typeof(T).Name}_Get", new { Id = id }, trans);
    
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        
    }
    
    return null;
}

you can do the same on the Delete method as well.

thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for. (thanks also to @mjwills for his comment yesterday along the same lines)
